# How to get out from an unpaid car loan?

Tags: united-states, auto-loan

I met with a gentleman from church today with a rather unique situation that I wasn't sure how to deal with. Two years ago he impulse bought a new car in IL @ 19% interest (poor credit) so he'd have reliable transportation for his kids. Within days he tried to take it back but the dealer wouldn't budge. Anyway, within weeks he lost his job and has not made a single payment! He recently got another job but only brings in about $800/month, and custody arrangements and school are keeping him from taking more hours or a different job. Ideally, he needs to get rid of this $25,000 vehicle and into something much cheaper but still reliable, but I'm not sure what he needs to do to get out of this. He's told the lender in the past to just take it, but nothing has happened. He said he's not even received any collection notifications.

Comment: @yoozer8 Not really. I don't see any of those as viable options. He doesn't have the income to make the payments, his credit score is way to low to get a different loan and he's way upside down since the car is now 2 years old yet the principle owed is the same as when he bought it. I would have thought they would have at least tried to repo it by now.

Comment: @TomTom How do you suggest he force them to repo it then? There's no way he'll be able to pay this or any other loan for this vehicle for quite some time. Not sure what he'll do if and when they finally do since he can't afford any auto loan at this point, but he'll worry about that when the time comes.

Comment: Bankruptcy. This is how society has agreed to handle people not able to handle their obligations.

Comment: @TomTom OK. I was wondering if that might be the best recourse for him.

Comment: @topshot the way to handle "needs a car, cannot get a loan" is to find a car that is sufficiently old/small/etc that you can buy it with cash (and then be wary of the mechanic's fees).

Comment: @topshot , looks like it has been 24 months ?  How many payments did he make, and, then how many since he just stopped making them?  He has not received ONE collection?

Comment: Was it a new car?  ($25,000 when new)  If so it will now be worth 8 or 9 thousand if that.

Comment: The insurance must be incredibly high monthly.

Comment: In this situation, what reason would the person have to go bankrupt? I don't understand?

Comment: @Fattie As stated, he's made NO payments on this new car. There was a downpayment initially, but that only affects initial principle for the loan. He doesn't have insurance either. He's been essentially homeless the past couple years. I wonder if the "bad credit" insurance policy that was part of the deal somehow paid this off??? I'd never seen such a thing (is it like PMI?), but I didn't read through the policy either.

Comment: @topshot thanks for the info.  It sounds like a huge corporation was stupid enough to give the person a loan, as part of their desperation to drive lending levels as high as possible.  Person should just continue as he is doing.   Again, to literally answer your question, there is absolutely no possibility, whatsoever, to "refinance" or the like.  I've expanded my answer based on your info, too

Comment: What is the current loan amount, and what is the current value of the car (based on year, model, miles, condition)?

Comment: @TTT My guess of the current amount would be original principle ($25k) plus 19% plus 19% since it has gone 2 years now with no principle reduction or interest paid. Don't know the miles but it's a 2018 Jeep Renegade in good shape.

Comment: @topshot I may be reading too much into the question, and being overly cynical... but especially if this is a new(ish) acquaintance, be cautious if he follows up this tale of hardship with any kind of offer/suggestion/request that you somehow help him financially: whether that be lend him some money to "help me sort things out", or to buy the car from him, especially if it's at a "seems too good to be true" price. Of course, he could be a genuine person in genuine hardship, but if the contact had been over the internet, such a tale would scream "scam".

Comment: @TripeHound I've only known him a few months, but others I know have known him a year or more. He asked for help on how to manage his finances better, which is why I offered to assist with educating him. This car situation, which I didn't know about beforehand, has been especially concerning him.

Answer (score 3):

If you owe 25,000, you're a bad person.

If you owe 25 million, you're the bank's best customer.

If you owe 25 trillion, you're a government.

If some bank / credit company was idiotic enough to loan the fellow the money, that company will have to deal with it.

OP reports that they have not received "even one collection notice".

They should just continue to do nothing, drive the car, and go about life.

The worst thing that can possibly happen is someone official-looking will come and take away the car.

If they literally cannot make the payments - literally, what other option is there?

Maybe in the future the person will be able to resume payments.  Maybe the person will die, win the lottery, get a better job, or maybe the horse will talk. Who knows?

The simple fact is if they literally cannot make the payments there is literally no other option, than to just carry on.

---

Note that since the loan is incredibly upside down, there is **absolutely no possibility** to "change to another car".  Forget it.  Drive safely.

---

> *As stated, he's made NO payments on this new car. There was a downpayment initially, but that only affects initial principle for the loan. He doesn't have insurance either. He's been essentially homeless the past couple years.*

**The "only leverage"** the finance world has **over you** is that it can "ruin your credit".  Evidently that is a non-issue in this case.  There is just literally nothing they can do.  They've made no-faith efforts at all to even contact. There is literally nothing "bad" that can happen to the person in this case.

It sounds like a huge corporation was stupid enough to give the person a loan, as part of their desperation to drive lending levels as high as possible. Person should just continue as he is doing.